# Shopify API - update selected variant with javascript using select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, shopify-api

In the product page I have a few select field for options. When I manually select all is fine and variant is selected but when I change option value using javascript like:

```
document.querySelector("[action='/cart/add']").getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value = 'S';
```

then I see that the select value is changed but there is no changed variant, so when I add to the cart the old value added

[image]

Comment: when you settings the value of select element, you need to also trigger the change event to change the value of selected variant.

Comment: I already try using jQuery: $('#SingleOptionSelector-0').val('T55').change();
 and $('#SingleOptionSelector-0').val('T55').trigger('change'); but nothing happend